# Using FinanceApp.getHistoricalStockInfo - regular trading hours only

Tags: google-apps-script

As per the Google Apps script help docs, the getHistoricalStockInfo function "Gets historical information for a given stock as a series of daily snapshots."

It appears that this function returns **all** prices for the stock including pre-market and after-hours market, but we are looking for prices during regular trading hours only.  (Regular trading hours are 9:30 AM - 4:00 PM EST on the major exchanges, but stocks such as GOOG start trading at 4:00 AM on the NASDAQ)

Is it possible to specify 'regular exchange trading hours only', or perhaps specify hour/minute time frames with this function?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve only the 9:30AM-4:00PM regular trading session data, all minute data for the entire day must be retrieved using getHistoricalIntradayStockInfo, then some aggregation must be performed on the intervals it returns.

for example:

```
// -- get the opening price for the regular trading day which starts at 9:30 AM EST 
ticker = "BAC";
date = new Date(2014,1,21);
var quoteDate = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(),9,30); // add 9:30 to the startdate for market open
var stock_info = FinanceApp.getHistoricalIntradayStockInfo(ticker, quoteDate , quoteDate, FinanceApp.Interval.ONE_MINUTE).stockInfo
return stock_info[0].open;
```

The only issue is the sheer amount of data this type of query can return depending on your date range.   This makes it difficult to solve problems like "was my stop loss triggered within this date range during regular trading hours?" (stop losses aren't typically triggered outside RTH)

Using the above method, using date ranges longer than a few weeks will cause Google to complain with a 'Argument too large' error.

Ideally, Google would either 
a) add a 'session' attribute to their getHistoricalStockInfo method, to specify regular or extended trading ours..

OR

b) Add a new FinanceApp.Interval type called 'DAILY' - this ideally would return pre-aggregated data with only 4 values (o,h,l,c) for each interval.